# How to extend the background processing time using lib react-native-background-actions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For my use case, I need to maintain a socket connection for iOS even in the background mode. To achieve this, I am using the `react-native-background-actions` library. It works well for around 25 seconds of background time, but it appears that the background functionality stops working after that.

Here's the code snippet I'm using to start the background task:

```
const startBackground = async () => {
  await BackgroundService.start(veryIntensiveTask, options);
  await BackgroundService.updateNotification({
    taskDesc: 'New ExampleTask description',
  });
  // Note: Only applicable for Android, iOS will ignore this call
  // iOS will continue to run everything here in the background until .stop() is called
  // await BackgroundService.stop();
};
```

I'm initiating the background task whenever the app enters the background state using the following code:

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    // Implementing react-native-background-actions for iOS only
    if (nextAppState === 'background') {
      startBackground();
    } else {
      stopBackground();
    }
  }
  setAppState(nextAppState);
});
```

The background stuff works for a while which is around 20-30s but in my usecase i want to keep the socket connection alive for more than a minute. So i want to know how can i extend the socket connection.

Comment: I don't think this is possible - if your messages are only coming to the app (and not going from the app) you could use silent push notifications instead; otherwise you're subject to background task limitations (run every ~15 min)

Comment: So what if I need to know the background updates every 2min of time? Because as far as I know, If I use a background timer library like react-native-background-fetch it won't let me do anything faster than 15 mins right?

Comment: Yep that's my understanding

Answer (score 0):

**TO WHOM IT CONCERNS**

So there is no way to *extend* the background time limited by OS. It might get extended on an iOS simulator but won't work on a real device. Whatever workaround you play, it will be eventually suspended by OS. I have researched and gone through various docs, and articles but none helped so I have decided to use FCM/APNs in order to awaken the app out of the background. It doesn't matter if your app is in QUIT or background state, it will wake the app out of the background and you can do your stuff in that background handler. FYI, I checked it both on the simulator as well as physical device and it worked as expected.